# Calculate distance between two pupils in 3Dimention in ARFaceTrackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, arkit, face

I have created a **facegeometry** as follows;

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    private var faceGeo: ARSCNFaceGeometry?
```

Using following to create Face;

```
faceGeo = ARSCNFaceGeometry.init(device: sceneView.device!, fillMesh: true);
```

To get the pupil of the Right Eye, I am using **VNFaceLandmarks2D**.

After getting pupil points I am doing a hit test with:

```
 self.faceGeo?.update(from: anchor.geometry)

 let PointRightPupil = face.landmarks?.rightPupil?.pointsInImage(imageSize: self.sceneView.bounds.size).first

 let resultRPupil = self.sceneView.hitTest(PointRightPupil!, options: [:])
```

But the ***resultRPupil*** is ***nill***.

I am trying to get X,Y,Z coordinated for the right pupil.

I want to calculate distance between two pupils in 3Dimention using face Geometry data provided by iPhone X front **CameraAR**.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Did you solve it by chance?